# mount: unknown filesystem type 'drbd'

Tags: types, filesystems, drbd

On two system with DRBD over LVM Logical Volumes, Primary/Secondary after a try change (promote) Secondary to Primary, get an error on TWO nodes.

```
Kernel panic on Centos System
```

Well.. i like fsck one or other nodes....

But get a wrong message.

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'drbd'
fsck /dev/sata/vm-100-disk-1
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
fsck: fsck.drbd: not found
fsck: Error 2 while executing fsck.drbd for /dev/mapper/sata-vm--100--disk--1
```

Desesperate... any info on Google.. Ask. Stack...

Answer (score 0):

This is the backing store, not the DRBD device - you shouldn't EVER perform modifications to the backing store.

```
Usage
 ^
DRBD
 ^ 
LVM
 ^
Disks
```

Basically you're pulling out the rug from DRBD - it replicates on the upper layer and relies on the lower layer being static. You should be doing an fsck on the DRBD device in /dev/drbd. (I use the named devices in /dev/drbd/by-res/